# Why is there so much difference between the WAMP and MAMP servers?

Tags: size, wamp, mamp

The size of the WAMP server installation size is 26.8mb whereas MAMP server is close to 150 mb. Are both genuine setup files?

Answer (score 0):

Well thats the right sort of size for WAMP. Remember they are different so MAMP may include things other than just Apache/MySQL/PHP